# Best Practice for Checking Dependent Variables Before or inside Method

Tags: java, methods, coding-style, call

I was wondering what the best practices would be for when you have a variable that needs to be checked before a certain helper method could run. Should the check be done in the caller or callee? I see benefits to both. A bit less expensive to do it in the caller method (before calling the helper method) but that puts the checks on the developers shoulders and something may get lost if the code switches hands (which it will do). Thus, that's the benefit of having it in the callee. A very crude example of what I mean is below

```
public class TestClass implements TestInterface {

    private String dependentVariable = null;

    public TestClass(arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(String flag) {
        this.dependentVariable = flag;
        caller();
    }

    public void caller() {
        //do it here?
        if(this.dependentVariable != null)
            callee();
    }

    public void callee() {
        //or do the check here?
        // do stuff involving the dependentVariable...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle this in `init()` itself. If your class behaviour is dependent on this variable you should not let your class get initialized with `null` in the first place.

```
@Override
public void init(String flag) {
    if (flag == null)
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Flag cannot be null");
    this.dependentVariable = flag;
    caller();
}
```

If the absence of the `flag` is okay and should just preempt the execution of `callee()`, it should be handled within `callee()` itself.

```
public void callee() {
    if (flag == null) return;
    // do stuff involving the dependentVariable...
}
```

This is because, as the code base grows, you would not be able to check if `flag` is being `null` checked everywhere prior to calling `callee()`. This falls in line with the DRY principle too.

Answer (score 0):

In your example it would be a good idea to make callee private, or at least protected, to minimize the possible misuse of it. It is usually a good idea to have checks like that right before using a sensitive variable but in some cases that is not practical or feasible for various reasons.

I would say that I prefer having the check in `callee` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to check inside the called method. The object should guarantee a consistent state. It can be easily illustrated by the following example: suppose that you implement a Money class:

```
public class Money {
    private final BigDecimal value;

    private Money(BigDecimal value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Money valueOf(BigDecimal value) {
        return new Money(value);
    }

    public BigDecimal getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The contract says the Money value must be positive. So If you pass the responsibility to the client to check if the value used to build the Money is positive, you are allowing someone to build a Money with non positive value, then your Money object is no more reliable and the code is harder to maintain.